# How to detect and/or enable developer mode in Android, using the sdk?

Tags: android, stress-testing

How to detect and/or enable developer mode in Android, using the sdk?

I already know about this:

```
boolean isDebuggable =  ( 0 != ( getApplicationInfo().flags &= ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE ) );
```

But this is not what I'm looking for. I want to see if the developer mode is enabled ("USB Debugging"), and if possible enable it.

Comment: You definitely cannot enable it.

Comment: Is it possible to check if it is enabled?